# FileSystemWatcher not working when files are changed via network under Win7

Tags: c#, networking, windows-7, filesystemwatcher

fikrst of all, let me try to explain what I do: I have a process that runs on startup of Windows 7 (Run-Entry in Registry). That process needs to be informed about changes in a specific textfile that is located on the same computer, but the changes are coming from another system via SMB on the local network, i.e. there is a file called c:\temp\MyFileToWatch.txt on this computer, and this file is altered (c:\temp is shared) from another computer on the local subnet.

I have implemented a filesystemwatcher in C# like this:

```
FileSystemWatcher incoming = new FileSystemWatcher();
        incoming.Path = @"c:\temp\";
        incoming.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName |
                                NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                                NotifyFilters.LastWrite |
                                NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        incoming.Filter = "MyFileToWatch.txt";
        incoming.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        incoming.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

and in OnChanged, I output a message like this:

```
public static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : MyFileToWatch.txt changed", System.DateTime.Now);
    }
```

The problem I have now is that the file is actually changed, but I do not get the notifications, at least as long as MyFileToWatch.txt is not opened in any program on the current computer. If however I open this file in an editor, the file changes are correctly noticed, and OnChanged is actaully called. If the file is not opened locally, I get no events.

This is what my log looks like when I run my process, and MyFileToWatch.txt is altered several times (I only get the first alteration):

```
8/31/2012 10:24:58 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
```

If however my file is open in an editor like Ultraedit, my log looks like this:

```
8/31/2012 10:10:37 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:08 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:15 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:18 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:20 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:31 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:48 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:54 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:11:59 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:12:06 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
8/31/2012 10:12:25 AM : MyFileToWatch.txt Changed
```

Does anybody have an explanation for that strange behaviour? The stranges part is, that under windows XP, it works in both cases, but under Win7, it does not.

How can I reliably get information about filechanges even if the file is not locally open in an editor?

Thanks alot.

Comment: FileSystemWatcher is notoriously unreliable.

Comment: Instead of using `FileSystemWatcher` you could use a timer to examine the file for changes at regular intervals, say once every second.

Comment: try attaching to all the events and see if the others fire.